# Link promise to another

Tags: scala, promise, future

I'm reading [scala.concurrent.impl.Promise](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala) and am confused by the concept "link DefaultPromise with another". I understand the 'prevent memory leak' part, but don't know how to write an example where the current state of `DefaultPromise` is `DefaultPromise`.

When `DefaultPromise` is first created, its state is `Nil` and the list grows as we keep appending `flatMap` to it. Under what circumstances is the branch

```
case dp: DefaultPromise[_] => dp.asInstanceOf[DefaultPromise[S]].linkRootOf(p)
```

in `Future.flatMap` called?

```
  test("default promise linking") {
    //f1.getState === Nil
    val f1 = Future {Thread.sleep(200000); 2}

    //f1.getState === List(CallbackRunner1)
    f1.flatMap(x => Future {Thread.sleep(200000); 4})
    //f1.getState === List(CallbackRunner2, CallbackRunner1)
    f1.flatMap(y => Future {Thread.sleep(200000); 3})

    Thread.sleep(30000000)
  }
```

Comment: Maybe `f1.flatMap(x => f1)`?

Comment: @Bergi, but how to understand **link promise to another so both promise share the same externally-visible state**?

Comment: `Future {Thread.sleep(200000); 4}` returns a `DefaultPromise`, right?

Comment: yeah, but how to understand **share same externally visible state**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this example:

```
val f1 = Future {Thread.sleep(200000); 2}
val f2 = f1.flatMap(x => {
    val f3 = Future {Thread.sleep(200000); 4}
    f3
})
```

`f1` and `f3` will of course not share the same state - one resolves with `2` the other with `4`. But when `f1` completes, the handler (`f(v)`) will create `f3` and it will match [the `case`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L255) that you are confused about. Then, `f2` (`p` in `flatMap`) will be linked to `f3` so that they share the same state.

Comment: I did a write-up on this here: https://github.com/viktorklang/blog/blob/master/Futures-in-Scala-2.12-part-9.md

Comment: can you elaborate on how **ACPS** break the chains of promise? How **ACPS** cut the link between flatMaps?

Comment: @vincentchou: It seems the point is that you *need* linking in `flatMap` when you use ACPS, not that ACPS is a solution of the memory problem.

Comment: @ViktorKlang Btw, for anyone interested in promise implementations, you might want to have a look at https://github.com/briancavalier/creed/pull/9. It features a new approach which fixes the problem [mentioned here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala#L132) that plain link collapsing has.

Comment: @Bergi that was a pretty massive PR, got any direct links to where the magic happens? :)

Comment: @ViktorKlang: Oops, it includes a few many commits indeed. Relevant is everything from ["alternative approach to shorten reference chains"](https://github.com/briancavalier/creed/pull/9/commits/054ef5c44ab517eb5e4ce2b9686772e7664b1bab) and following